# Is is possible to pass a variable from one process to another?

Tags: c

let's say I have 2 processes and I have a variable I want to pass from the first one to the second one. I know I can declare a global variable and pass it by reference among differents functions, but I don't know if it is possible to pass a variable among different processes.

I heard that each process is assigned its own portion of virtual memory and that one process cannot access another process' memory space. Is it that true? Or is is actually possible for two processes to share a variable and therefore mutex mechanisms are needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't know if it is possible to pass a variable among different processes.

No, it is not possible, at least not in the classical sense of passing a variable. You have many options, though: inter-process communication can be done through shared memory (sometimes implemented through memory-mapped files), named pipes, etc.

Answer (score 4):

> Or is is actually possible for two processes to share a variable and therefore mutex mechanisms are needed?

Yes, you should look up shared memory, or more generally, IPC / interprocess communication.

Answer (score 1):

If the second process is started from the first one, you could pass it as command line parameter.

Otherwise you should rely on some inter-process communication method (like Socket or FIFO, also known as named pipe).

You could have a look to this other post:

[Interprocess Communication via file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062444/interprocess-communication-via-file/11062480#11062480)